# How can I change the stdout baud rate in ESP-IDF?

Tags: serial-port, stdout, baud-rate, esp-idf

I wrote a small program on PlatformIO for an ESP32 with ESP-IDF framework.

Currently this is connected to my PC with USB cable.
I receive lots of data from a CAN-BUS and I print this data with printf()

It seems the output with the standard baud rate 115200 is too slow. This is why I want to set this to a higher value.

I changed this in the platformio.ini without success.

```
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I searched and did not find where I can change this baud rate.

If possible my idea is to add some code, maybe just a line or two, to set the value i.e. to 230400

I mention the ESP32, PlatformIO and ESP-IDF because I am not sure where this setting is supposed to be.

Answer (score 5):

It is a setting of *esp-idf* framework. You can set the console baud rate in ***sdkconfig.defaults*** (at project root directory):

```
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE=230400
```

You can also configure it via *menuconfig* (**idf.py menuconfig** or **pio run -t menuconfig**):

- Component config

  - Common ESP-related

    - UART console baud rate

Comment: On ESP32 S3 there is no such option, and if I change sdkconfig manually, it restored to 115200 after build.

Comment: This setting was renamed to __ESP_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE__ in new versions of esp-idf framework.

Comment: I've succeeded to open baud rate option by selecting "Custom" / UART0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSC and ESP-IDF extension,
go to settings (default CTRL+,) -> Extensions -> ESP-IDF -> Flash Baud Rate
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On VSCode:
Open Settings and search vor "baud".
Don' t change "Flash Baud Rate", it is "Monitor Baud Rate" you want to adjust!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Qm9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using ESP-IDF directly (VSCode ESP-IDF extension). For PlatformIO the is not so different.

My device is ESP32-S3.

There are two thing you want to change:

- ***IDE serial monitor baudrate*** - the baudrate the IDE monitor is expecting.
- ***ESP32 console output baudrate*** - the baudrate of the ESP32 device for the UART used for console output.

## Setting the IDE Serial Monitor Baudrate

For ESP-IDF extension, go to the ***settings***, type `esp-ifd baud rate` in the search box, you will get two results: ***"ESP-IDF Flash Baud rate"*** and ***"ESP-IDF Monitor Baud rate"***. The monitor is the one you are looking for. Set it the value you want e.g. 230400.

For PlatformIO extension, you can set the monitor speed by adding/changing the  `monitor_speed` option in ***platformio.ini***, e.g. `monitor_speed = 230400`.

## Setting the ESP32 Console Output Baudrate

There are two ways I found.

#### 1. Hard code the baudrate

The default console output is `UART0`, so right at the beginning of the program add: `uart_set_baudrate(UART_NUM_0, 230400)`:

```c
#include "driver/uart.h"

void app_main() 
{
    uart_set_baudrate(UART_NUM_0, 230400);
    
    // ...
}
```

When using this option, the serial monitor may output some garbage before the code reaches this line do to some init code logs that are sent before changing the baudrate to what the monitor is expecting.

#### 2. Configure ESP-IDF sdkconfig File

To open a configuration editor, for ESP-IDF you can use the command `ESP-IDF: SDK Configuration editor` (or the corresponding icon) or type `idf.py menuconfig` (for PlatformIO `pio run -t menuconfig`) in the terminal.

The configurations you want to change are:

1. ***Component config -> ESP System Settings -> Channel for console
   output***:
   Set it to `Custom UART`.
2. ***Component config -> ESP System
   Settings -> UART peripheral to use for console output (0-1)***:
   Set it
   to `UART0`.
3. ***Component config -> ESP System Settings -> UART console
   baud rate***:
   Set it to the value you want e.g. 230400.

P.S. The ***CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE*** option of the ***sdkconfig*** is no longer supported, see [ESP-IDF Monitor](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/migration-guides/release-5.x/5.0/tools.html#esp-idf-monitor).